# How to make if statement in react plugin?

Tags: plugins, block-editor

I Create Guttenberg pluggin by react. My problem is that I cannot use if statement.

```
 const priceforextrashop =  parseFloat(props.priceextra)
 const priceforegoodshop = parseFloat(props.pricegoood)
 const priceforstandardshop = parseFloat(props.pricestandard)
 const priceforsmallshop = parseFloat(props.pricesmall)
   React.useEffect(() => {
     if(wynik<20000){
      setPrice(priceforextrashop);
    }
     if(wynik<15000){
      setPrice(priceforegoodshop);
    }
     if(wynik<10000){
      setPrice(priceforstandardshop);
    }
   if(wynik<5000){
    setPrice(priceforsmallshop);
  }

}, [wynik]);
```

props.prices reffer to attritubutes I add on editor-block side of plugin. The value work good, I  exposed them on screen.
problem is just with these if statement because always show the same value.
I know that the if statement should work good because on editor-black side or in another scripts, I put the same if statement and it worked.
Please indicate me answer.

update:

I add dependence "wynik" but it not resolve my problem. Just count 2from 4 variables not all of them.
I try without useEffect but then it make an error.

Comment: Are you trying to use this for controls in the editor, for configuring the block, or are you creating a block that has React interactivity on the front end? Can you include a full block of code so we can see the context of these snippets?

Comment: Ok, I hope, I update the question correctly

Comment: Your `if` conditions do not terminate the `useEffect()` function. So for example, if `wynik` is `1000` your code will execute `setPrice(priceforextrashop)` then `setPrice(priceforegoodshop)` then `setPrice(priceforstandardshop)` and finally `setPrice(priceforsmallshop)`. Consider adding `else` controls or inserting `return` statements.